# convergence of $\sum_{n≥ 1}\left(n^{-1-\frac{1}{n}}\right)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I want to determine the convergence of the series and to do so, consider that

$$\sum_{n≥ 1}\left(n^{-1-\frac{1}{n}}\right)=\sum_{n≥ 1}\left(n^{\frac{-n-1}{n}}\right)$$

I consider at first glance that the series converges, and to determine this I was thinking of using the limit comparison test; however I would have to find a sequence $b_n$ such that $\frac{a_n}{b_n}=L≥0$ Clearly where $b_n$ converges.

Any help? or any other way to approach this? thanks.

Comment: note that $n^{1/n} \le 2, n \ge 2$ so $n^{-1-\frac{1}{n}} \ge 1/(2n), n \ge 2$ what do you conclude?

Comment: I was thinking of using the basic comparison test, and since $\sum_{n≥2}\frac{1}{2n}$ diverges then the serie I am studying would also diverge, right?

Comment: If $a_n=n^{-1-\frac{1}{n}}$ then $$2^n a_{2^n}=2^{-\frac{n}{2^n}}\longrightarrow 1 $$ So, you series diverges by cauchy condensation.

Answer (score 0):

You have
$$
n^{-1-\frac{1}{n}} = \frac{1}{n\cdot n^{\frac{1}{n}}} = \frac{1}{n \cdot e^{\frac{\ln n}{n}}} 
$$
Now, what is the limit of $e^{\frac{\ln n}{n}}$, and can you use this to conclude?